# Постановка знаков препинания при вопросе внутри предложения

Tags: запятые, тире, прямая-речь, двоеточие, вопрос

Скажите, пожалуйста, верно ли в этом предложении поставлены знаки препинания или нет? Если нет, то как их правильно поставить? Можно ли это сделать, не перестраивая предложение полностью?

*Был лишь вопрос от игрока в чате, какие правила, но ему никто не ответил.*

P. S.
Почему при написании этого сообщения система удаляет слово "здравствуйте"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно оформить так: *Был лишь вопрос **«какие правила?»** от игрока в чате, но ему никто не ответил.*

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159
**Примечание.** Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.); С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Comment: Тогда с заглавной надо, есть обобщающее слово - с криком "Спасите...", лишь вопрос "Какие правила?". (Не очень люблю это правило именно за невнятность: примеры без обобщающего со строчной, с обобщающим с заглавной, но является ли это правилом - нет указаний. При этом есть еще обобщающие, при которых нужно добавить двоеточие, но ни их значение, ни перечень тоже не указаны).